# Can I control parallelism of concurrentPerform?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I wrote a routine that uses DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations:execute:) and uses it in multi-thread programming.

I was surprised that the performance was better when I put meanless iteration of queue.sync in an other function by mistake.
The iteration let concurrentPerform use more cores in A12X Bionic.

Certainly [Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW5) says,

> Many factors affect the number of tasks executed by the concurrent queues, including the number of available cores, the amount of work being done by other processes, and the number and priority of tasks in other serial dispatch queues.

I want to achieve the better performance by reasonable manner.
How can I control the parallelism of concurrentPerform?

Changing QoS of queue to .userInitiated had no effect.

Thanks.

Comment: there is one more QoS .userInteractive which has higher priority, try it

Answer (score 1):

let's try it! next example do the simple job two different ways, first dispatching all jobs asynchronously on .default .concurrent queue, next using DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform.

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform is very nice and easy to use construct.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let q = DispatchQueue(label: "internal", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent)
func job()->String {
    var sum  = 0
    for i in 1...1000 {
        let r = Int.random(in: 0..<i)
        sum += r
    }
    let res = sum.description
    return res
}

func asyncFoo(on: DispatchQueue, id: Int, completition: @escaping (_ id: Int, _ result: String)->()) {

    on.async {
        let res = job()
        completition(id, res)
    }
}

let group = DispatchGroup()

var start = Date()

for i in 0..<10 {
    group.enter() // enter the group before the task starts
    asyncFoo(on: q, id: i) { (id, result) in
        print("id:", id, i, result)
        group.leave() // leave the group when task finished
    }
}
group.notify(queue: .main) {
    var stop = Date()
    print("all asynchronously dispatched done in", stop.timeIntervalSince(start), "seconds")
    let task: (Int)->() = { i in
        let res = job()
        print("id:", i, res)
    }
    print("continue again ...")
    start = Date()
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 10, execute: task)
    stop = Date()
    print("all .concurrentPerform done in", stop.timeIntervalSince(start), "seconds")
    PlaygroundPage.current.finishExecution()
}
print("continue execution ...")
```

and what about the result?

```
continue execution ...
id: 7 7 251189
id: 2 2 252628
id: 8 8 248525
id: 5 5 248212
id: 0 0 254412
id: 3 3 255094
id: 6 6 260566
id: 1 1 242460
id: 9 9 247018
id: 4 4 246296
all asynchronously dispatched done in 0.10741996765136719 seconds
continue again ...
id: 2 248549
id: 3 245366
id: 7 242868
id: 8 252247
id: 0 250905
id: 4 249909
id: 6 247525
id: 9 246204
id: 1 253908
id: 5 249081
all .concurrentPerform done in 0.05399894714355469 seconds
```

If available, I prefer to use .concurrentPerform, but it really depends ... There is no API to change anything on .concurrentPerform, but most likely it will be your best performer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you tell me how to make the performance of concurrentPerform better? That is my question.

Comment: @Yuji, you don't have anything to adjust, my example tried to show you, that most likely your own design will be worst. Just use it "as is". The OS (at least on Apple platforms) does "the best" for you. If you worry about synch behavior, dispatch the whole thing asynchronously, that's all.

Comment: @Yuji, if you've experienced bad performance, show us the code, most probably the trouble is somewhere else there. Even though the name is .concurrentPerform, it is designed for parallel execution